# Do Banach spaces and linear contraction maps form a model of ILL with an exponential?

Tags: lo.logic, linear-algebra, ct.category-theory, topology, linear-logic

Recently, I read on the nLab that [the category of Banach spaces and linear contractions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Banach+space) is small complete, small cocomplete, and monoidal closed.

This means that Banach spaces and short linear maps form a model of intuitionistic multiplicative-additive linear logic, and the fact that it is small (co)complete seems to suggest that the construction of Melliès, Tabareau
and Tasson in [*An explicit formula for the free exponential
modality of linear logic*](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00391714/document) would go through in this category, supplying an interpretation of the exponential as well.

I found this quite surprising, since interpreting linear logic in infinite-dimensional vector spaces seems to have prompted an awful lot of work over the last two decades.

1. Does this model for ILL with an exponential actually work? I haven't seen it before in the literature, so maybe it fails for some obvious reason that I am overlooking...
2. If so, what is the motivation for placing so much emphasis on finding  models of specifically *classical* linear logic in (some restriction of) infinite-dimensional vector spaces?

Comment: Hi Neel!  Are you sure that the category in question is monoidal closed?  The nLab page is quite confusing because it talks about closure of the category $\mathbf{Ban}$ after the definition of bounded operator, but then it defines $\mathbf{Ban}$ as the category whose morphisms are linear contractions.  The latter category does not seem closed to me: the set of linear contractions on a space is not even a vector space (the identity $\mathsf I$ is a linear contraction, $\mathsf I+\mathsf I$ is not).  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, ok, I see what's going on, it's explained further down the article and then at the [internal hom](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom) page.  My first reaction then would be that Melliès, Tabareau and Tasson's construction won't work because the underlying limit does not commute with the tensor.  But I don't know, I'm just saying this because, like you say, finding a TVS model of linear logic is not easy, in particular because the Kleisli category will give you a "convenient" category of vector spaces (e.g. cartesian closed), which is rare and would have not gone unnoticed...

Comment: Oh yeah, I forgot that you have to check the limit commutes with the tensor. That gives a natural next thing to check. I had a vague assumption that the big problem with TVS models was that the double-dual didn't work the way you want, and this webpage made me wonder "why not look at ILL?"

Comment: Quick update: I've been discussing this with people much more knowledgeable than me on the topic, so far it seems that there is no obstruction to $\mathbf{Ban}$ being a model of ILL.  In particular, the fact that the tensor commutes with the projective limit required in MTT's construction seems to be a well-known fact (c.f. Theorem 15.4.2 in Hans Jarchow's book *Locally Convex Spaces*).  So it may actually be a model after all!  As soon as I'll have collected more precise and definitive evidence (if not a proof), I'll write an answer.

Comment: I'm looking forward to this!